# .htaccess Rewrite with Original Request Appended to Query String

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, pdf, mod-rewrite

I have a directory in my site with a bunch of temporary PHP generated PDF files.

> mysite.com/crm/pdfs/

I have an .htaccess file located in the pdfs/ directory with the intention of redirecting all requests within that folder to the index.php page within that folder and include the original request in the query string. For example,

When a browser is pointed to:

> mysite.com/crm/pdfs/somepdf.pdf

it should be redirected to

> mysite.com/crm/pdfs/index.php?p=somepdf.pdf

Here's my current try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The problem with this is, when the user requests:

> mysite.com/crm/pdfs/somepdf.pdf

They are instead redirected to

> mysite.com/index.php

and the original request is not appended.

How can I achieve the desired result in my .htaccess that is located in the /pdfs directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this rule in your `/pdfs/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /crm/pdfs/

RewriteRule ^(.+?\.pdf)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: well, this is the closest I've gotten so far. Now, when the pdf is requested I am transferred to the 404 page inside that directory instead of being brought all the way back out to the main index page. There is an index.php inside of that directory.

Comment: Is your full URL this: `mysite.com/crm/pdfs/somepdf.pdf`? Try my updated rule now.